# Compile error: Next without For

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Searched but I think my code is correct now, but still get this dreaded compile error, but I cannot determine why!  Code is as follows:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

LastRow = Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value = "4125551212" Then
    Cells(i, 19).Value = ""

    Else
        If Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Offset(1, -6).Value And Cells(i, 19).Offset(1, -6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value Then
        Cells(i, 19).Value = "Y"

    Else
        If Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Offset(1, -6).Value Then
        Cells(i, 19).Value = "Y"

    Else
        If Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Offset(-1, -6).Value And Cells(i, 19).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Y" Then
        Cells(i, 19).Value = "Y"

    Else
        Cells(i, 19).Value = ""

End If

Next i
```

Comment: `If..End If` blocks can only have 1 `Else` block. If X then Y, else Z.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the `Else` positions:

```
Sub jhgf()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    LastRow = Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value = "4125551212" Then
            Cells(i, 19).Value = ""

            ElseIf Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Offset(1, -6).Value And Cells(i, 19).Offset(1, -6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value Then
                Cells(i, 19).Value = "Y"

            ElseIf Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Offset(1, -6).Value Then
                Cells(i, 19).Value = "Y"

            ElseIf Cells(i, 19).Offset(0, -6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Offset(-1, -6).Value And Cells(i, 19).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Y" Then
                Cells(i, 19).Value = "Y"

            Else
                Cells(i, 19).Value = ""

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```